# How can I read a braces delimited text file in a Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I have the  file txt having some lines , and here below is my txt file

```
rule.txt
----------------------------------------
direct
replace{100,1011}
replace{india,o891}
replace{1100,101}
-----------------------------------------
```

I need to capture the numbers in between open braces and closed brace using batch file.

Comment: (1) As a matter of names, `(` and `)` are called *parentheses.* They do look similar to braces: `{` and `}`. (2) What research have you done? What have you tried?

Comment: Starting pointers perhaps.... `FOR /F "USEBACKQ DELIMS={, TOKENS=2" %F IN ("C:\folder\text.txt") DO ECHO %~F` and `FOR /F "USEBACKQ DELIMS=}, TOKENS=2" %F IN ("C:\folder\text.txt") DO ECHO %~F`, and then you can use some logic to concat the two in order and perhaps replace non `int` with zero or whatever else you need. Your requirements are vague but I'd tackle with PowerShell myself for something like this rather than batch but those are some batch quick thought starting points with vague requirements perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

With a batch-file:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\12\26\SU_1387726.cmd
@Echo off
For /F "tokens=2,3 delims={,}" %%A IN (
   ' findstr "{" rule.txt'
) DO ECHO:%%A =^> %%B
```

sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\12\26\SU_1387726.cmd
100 => 1011
india => o891
1100 => 101
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to capture the data inside the curly braces then you may use the following powershell command.

```
Get-ChildItem rule.txt | Select-String -Pattern '(?<={).*?(?=})' | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
```

**Output**

```
100,1011
india,o891
1100,101
```